# Create like/unlike functionality with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a list of properties for a real estate application and im trying to implement a like/unlike functionality based on each property detail. The idea is to add a like or remove it matching the current property and user. This is my code so far, but it only remove likes so it doesnt work as expected. If anyone can suggest for a better approach ill be appreciated.

//Controller

```
public function storeLike($id)
{
    $like = Like::firstOrNew(array('property_id' => $id));
    $user = Auth::id();

    try{
        $liked = Like::get_like_user($id);
    }catch(Exception $ex){
        $liked = null;
    }

    if($liked){
        $liked->total_likes -= 1;
        $liked->status = false;
        $liked->save();
    }else{
        $like->user_id = $user;
        $like->total_likes += 1;
        $like->status = true;
        $like->save();
    }

    return Redirect::to('/detalle/propiedad/' . $id);
}
```

// Model

```
public static function get_like_user($id)
{
    return static::with('property', 'user')->where('property_id', $id)
                                           ->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
}
```

// Route

```
Route::get('store/like/{id}', array('as' => 'store.like', 'uses' => 'LikeController@storeLike'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrés Da Viá Looks like you are returning object from model. In case there is no data in database, it will still return an object - so far my guessing. Can you do something like below in the `if($liked){` code?

**Try this instead:**

```
if(isset($liked -> user_id)){
```

Also try to print **$liked** variable after try and catch blocks. Use `var_dump`.
If this still does not work for you then let me know. I will try to create code based on your question.

Comment: I have made a few changes in my code and it seems to work this way. First i check if there is a property with a given user like associated. If it is then i remove 1 from total_likes otherwise i add 1. The problem is that when $liked is already created it will always remove 1. So im wondering how to add 1 or remove 1 when like is already created

Comment: @AndrésDaViá Check the status? If `$liked` is present and `$liked -> status = FALSE` - that means it is unliked, then change the status to liked one. Same scenario goes for `status = TRUE`. If `$liked` is not present then its simple thing to put new status.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by adding a where clause in my model to make the status equal to True ->where('status', 1)->first();